# Usar variables al formular consulta para filtrar datos de una tabla

Tags: mysql, python, base-de-datos, python-2.7, tkinter

Estoy trabajando con Python y MySQL en una aplicación de Tkinter. Estoy tratando de hacer un filtro de búsqueda para que solo me muestre las entradas de mi tabla que correspondan a lo que ingreso con el teclado pero no se como establecerlo en la sentencia SQL.

La función que estoy usando para ello es:

```
def buscar():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "unitec", db = "efrias002")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM base17 WHERE usuario = 'fduran006'")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    for item in data:
        list1.insert(END,item)
    conn.close()
```

En este caso la sentencia anterior buscara en el campo "usuario" todo lo que contenga "fduran006" pero como puedo modificarlo para que busque lo que yo le indique mediante teclado. ¿Como debo modificar la parte del `WHERE` para lograr esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer usas tkinter aunque no muestras como obtienes el nombre por parte del usuario en tu app. Puedes obtener el texto de una StringVar (`usuario = variable.get()`), de un `Entry`, etc.

**Nunca uses el formateo de cadenas de Python (`%`, `str.format`, `f""`, concatenación, etc) para crear la consulta a partir de tus variables** ya que te expones a ataques de inyección SQL, en su lugar haz algo así:

```
usuario = busqueda_text.get() 
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM base17 WHERE usuario = %s;", (usuario,))
```

Dónde `busqueda_text` es una `StringVar`. El segundo argumento es un iterable, en este caso una tupla, prestar atención a la coma después de la variable, ya que de faltar los paréntesis son tratados como tales y no como indicativo de una tupla.

Hay [múltiples formas seguras](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) de pasar las variables, por ejemplo:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM base17 WHERE usuario = %(usr)s;", {"usr": usuario})
```

---

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM base17 WHERE usuario = (%s);", usuario)
```

---

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM base17 WHERE usuario = ?);", usuario)
```

---

Es decir, quedaría algo así:

```
def buscar():
    usuario = busqueda_text.get()
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "unitec", db = "efrias002")
    cursor = conn.cursor() 
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM base17 WHERE usuario = %s;", (usuario,))

    for item in cursor:
        list1.insert(END,item)

    conn.close()
```

Comment: Si de hecho estoy tratando de pasarlo desde un entry el cual es asi: busqueda_text=StringVar()
e7=Entry(ventana,textvariable=busqueda_text)
e7.grid(row=3,column=5)

Comment: @ErickFinn mira la edición a ver si te vale. La función `buscar` la lanzas al pulsar un botón supongo. Dado que tu `StringVar` es tratada como una variable global lo que te muestro debe funcionar en principio sin problemas.

Comment: si de hecho estoy haciendo una GUI en TKinter, entonces tengo un entry donde yo teclee por ejemplo "ghernandez" y al darle al boton "Buscar" me despliegue en la listbox solo los registros que coincidan. Cabe resaltar que ya tengo un boton llamado "mostrar" el cual despliega todos los registros de la tabla.

Comment: @ErickFinn el segundo argumento debe ser una tupla, debería ser `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM base17 WHERE usuario = %s", (res,))`. Observa la coma en `(res,)`, por supuesto que res debe ser una cadena (como la que obtienes con  `StringVar.get`)

Comment: Si, me di cuenta del error. Ya quedo. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar esto no debes olvidar que la query que le mandas es un String por lo que podes hacer algo asi

```
cursor.execute(QueryConFiltro(filtro));

public String QueryConFiltro(String filtro){

return "SELECT * FROM base17 WHERE usuario = '"+filtro+"'";

}
```